# Compile error - bitcoind Ubuntu 14.04 gcc and clang

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to install bitcoin server using this guide
https://www.sky-ip.org/configure-bitcoin-node-debian-ubuntu.html
However when I make, I see the error

```
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)  
Please submit a full bug report,  
with preprocessed source if appropriate.  
Making all in src  
make[1]: Entering directory /root/bitcoinsrc/bitcoin/src  
make[2]: Entering directory /root/bitcoinsrc/bitcoin/src  
CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-main.o  
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)  
Please submit a full bug report,  
with preprocessed source if appropriate.  
See file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs for instructions.  
make[2]: ** [libbitcoin_server_a-main.o] Error 4  
make[2]: Leaving directory /root/bitcoinsrc/bitcoin/src  
make[1]: ** [all-recursive] Error 1  
make[1]: Leaving directory /root/bitcoinsrc/bitcoin/src  
make: ** [all-recursive] Error 1'
```

Following advice to install and use clang instead, I can't get Ubuntu to actually use Clang:

When I try to make It still uses the old GCC.
When i try 'sudo apt-get update-alternatives --config c++'
    E: Command line option --config is not understood

When I try sudo update-alternatives --query c++ I get

```
Name: c++  
Link: /usr/bin/c++  
Slaves:  
c++.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/c++.1.gz  
Status: auto  
Best: /usr/bin/clang++-3.6  
Value: /usr/bin/clang++-3.6  

Alternative: /usr/bin/clang++-3.6  
Priority: 100  
Slaves:  

Alternative: /usr/bin/g++  
Priority: 20  
Slaves:  
c++.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/g++.1.gz
```

I want to be able to compile this somehow someway. This is my first time trying to compile so I am pretty unfamiliar with it. Please explain noobly

Comment: How much memory does your machine have? Because what you see is likely a work of Linux out-of-memory killer.

Comment: It says 512 ram 512 vswap. I am getting Out of memory in UB 3023: OOM killed process 12260 (cc1plus). Can I still use clang? Why won't it setup properly..I didn't know this could happen, can't it just compile slower?